# Excel count cells where the cell on the left isn't empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to count the amount of rows where the cell in column D is "Notebook" and the value of the respective cell of column C isn't empty. I tried countif but I couldn't figure out how it works properly.
[This is what the table looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mKC5.png)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
=countifs(d:d, "notebook", c:c, "<>")
```

Comment: Neat trick. Didn't know that `"<>"` can be used in `COUNTIFS` to search for non-blank cells. +1